# Porque em Portugal se diz Nazi e no Brasil Nazista?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Porque em Portugal se diz "nazi" e no Brasil "nazista"?

Ouvi na TV.

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido *nazi* em português. Sou brasileiro, por sinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na·zi
adjectivo de dois géneros

1. Relativo ao nazismo.

adjectivo de dois géneros e nome de dois géneros
2. Que ou quem é adepto do partido nacional-socialismo que Hitler chefiou.

**Sinónimo Geral: NAZISTA**

"nazi", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/nazi [consultado em 04-05-2023].